# Linux: I'm playing with John the ripper on my own machine, how do I output just the hashes?

Tags: linux

i want to use another service for teh hash cracking. Like a lookup table, ie http://www.onlinehashcrack.com/
How do I invoke john the ripper such that it doesn't try crackingthe passwords, but gives me the hashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As root (you can use `sudo`):

```
cat /etc/shadow
```

you don't need john to dump the hashes

Comment: is there a way to get them in a 0-9, A-F format?

Comment: base64 decode...you might find this thread helpful, although it is on a different topic: http://www.linux-archive.org/fedora-directory/220890-exporting-md5-hash-fd-ds-into-etc-shadow.html

Comment: for oddball distribution formats you might find this helpful: http://tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html